# $\tau_n = 2^{-n}(\lfloor2^n\tau\rfloor+1)$.$\tau$ is a stopping time.How to prove $\tau_n$ is a stopping time?

Tags: probability

$\tau_n = 2^{-n}(\lfloor2^n\tau\rfloor+1)$.$\tau$ is a stopping time.How to prove $\tau_n$ is a stopping time?

It is clear that $\tau$ is strictly less than $\tau_n$.But I just cannot show $\tau_n$ is a stopping time.I even doubt whether it is.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\{\tau_n=k/2^n\}=\{(k-1)/2^n\leqslant\tau\lt k/2^n\}\in\mathcal F_{(k/2^n)^-}\subseteq\mathcal F_{k/2^n}$$